# Generating Code 128 Barcodes using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, code128

I'm trying to get Code 128 barcodes generated in Excel, through the use of VBA. I've found a VBA class that somebody made and shared via VBForums (subsequently modified to work with Excel VBA), but I'm having problems getting it to work.

If I use the code below in an Excel Macro-enabled spreadsheet, I get the #VALUE error when trying to use the Code128_Str() function on any input.

I lack the necessary skills to debug the code properly. If this script can be corrected, I think it would be immensely useful to many people trying to do the same. The script in question uses the free font to generate the relevant Code 128 output barcodes.

References:
http://www.barcodeman.com/info/c128.php3 (Font Download)
http://www.vbforums.com/printthread.php?t=514742&pp=40&page=1 (Original Forum Thread with Code)

```
' ***    Made By Michael Ciurescu (CVMichael)   ***
'Modified by Paulo Cunha (pcunha) to work with char128.ttf on word or excel on 16/05/2011
'the font at in http://grandzebu.net/index.php?page=/informatique/codbar-en/code128.htm


' References:
' http://www.barcodeman.com/info/c128.php3

Private Enum eCode128Type
    eCode128_CodeSetA = 1
    eCode128_CodeSetB = 2
    eCode128_CodeSetC = 3
End Enum

Private Type tCode
    ASet As String
    BSet As String
    CSet As String
    BarSpacePattern As String
End Type

Private CodeArr() As tCode

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim CodeArr(106)

    AddEntry 0, " ", " ", "00", Chr(32)
    AddEntry 1, "!", "!", "01", Chr(33)
    AddEntry 2, """", """", "02", Chr(34)
    AddEntry 3, "#", "#", "03", Chr(35)
    AddEntry 4, "$", "$", "04", Chr(36)
    AddEntry 5, "%", "%", "05", Chr(37)
    AddEntry 6, "&", "&", "06", Chr(38)
    AddEntry 7, "'", "'", "07", Chr(39)
    AddEntry 8, "(", "(", "08", Chr(40)
    AddEntry 9, ")", ")", "09", Chr(41)
    AddEntry 10, "*", "*", "10", Chr(42)
    AddEntry 11, "+", "+", "11", Chr(43)
    AddEntry 12, ",", ",", "12", Chr(44)
    AddEntry 13, "-", "-", "13", Chr(45)
    AddEntry 14, ".", ".", "14", Chr(46)
    AddEntry 15, "/", "/", "15", Chr(47)
    AddEntry 16, "0", "0", "16", Chr(48)
    AddEntry 17, "1", "1", "17", Chr(49)
    AddEntry 18, "2", "2", "18", Chr(50)
    AddEntry 19, "3", "3", "19", Chr(51)
    AddEntry 20, "4", "4", "20", Chr(52)
    AddEntry 21, "5", "5", "21", Chr(53)
    AddEntry 22, "6", "6", "22", Chr(54)
    AddEntry 23, "7", "7", "23", Chr(55)
    AddEntry 24, "8", "8", "24", Chr(56)
    AddEntry 25, "9", "9", "25", Chr(57)
    AddEntry 26, ":", ":", "26", Chr(58)
    AddEntry 27, ";", ";", "27", Chr(59)
    AddEntry 28, "<", "<", "28", Chr(60)
    AddEntry 29, "=", "=", "29", Chr(61)
    AddEntry 30, ">", ">", "30", Chr(62)
    AddEntry 31, "?", "?", "31", Chr(63)
    AddEntry 32, "@", "@", "32", Chr(64)
    AddEntry 33, "A", "A", "33", Chr(65)
    AddEntry 34, "B", "B", "34", Chr(66)
    AddEntry 35, "C", "C", "35", Chr(67)
    AddEntry 36, "D", "D", "36", Chr(68)
    AddEntry 37, "E", "E", "37", Chr(69)
    AddEntry 38, "F", "F", "38", Chr(70)
    AddEntry 39, "G", "G", "39", Chr(71)
    AddEntry 40, "H", "H", "40", Chr(72)
    AddEntry 41, "I", "I", "41", Chr(73)
    AddEntry 42, "J", "J", "42", Chr(74)
    AddEntry 43, "K", "K", "43", Chr(75)
    AddEntry 44, "L", "L", "44", Chr(76)
    AddEntry 45, "M", "M", "45", Chr(77)
    AddEntry 46, "N", "N", "46", Chr(78)
    AddEntry 47, "O", "O", "47", Chr(79)
    AddEntry 48, "P", "P", "48", Chr(80)
    AddEntry 49, "Q", "Q", "49", Chr(81)
    AddEntry 50, "R", "R", "50", Chr(82)
    AddEntry 51, "S", "S", "51", Chr(83)
    AddEntry 52, "T", "T", "52", Chr(84)
    AddEntry 53, "U", "U", "53", Chr(85)
    AddEntry 54, "V", "V", "54", Chr(86)
    AddEntry 55, "W", "W", "55", Chr(87)
    AddEntry 56, "X", "X", "56", Chr(88)
    AddEntry 57, "Y", "Y", "57", Chr(89)
    AddEntry 58, "Z", "Z", "58", Chr(90)
    AddEntry 59, "[", "[", "59", Chr(91)
    AddEntry 60, "\", "\", "60", Chr(92)
    AddEntry 61, "]", "]", "61", Chr(93)
    AddEntry 62, "^", "^", "62", Chr(94)
    AddEntry 63, "_", "_", "63", Chr(95)
    AddEntry 64, Chr(0), "`", "64", Chr(96) ' Null
    AddEntry 65, Chr(1), "a", "65", Chr(97) ' SOH
    AddEntry 66, Chr(2), "b", "66", Chr(98) ' STX
    AddEntry 67, Chr(3), "c", "67", Chr(99) ' ETX
    AddEntry 68, Chr(4), "d", "68", Chr(100) ' EOT
    AddEntry 69, Chr(5), "e", "69", Chr(101) ' ENQ
    AddEntry 70, Chr(6), "f", "70", Chr(102) ' ACK
    AddEntry 71, Chr(7), "g", "71", Chr(103) ' BEL
    AddEntry 72, Chr(8), "h", "72", Chr(104) ' BS
    AddEntry 73, Chr(9), "i", "73", Chr(105) ' HT
    AddEntry 74, Chr(10), "j", "74", Chr(106) ' LF
    AddEntry 75, Chr(11), "k", "75", Chr(107) ' VT
    AddEntry 76, Chr(12), "l", "76", Chr(108) ' FF
    AddEntry 77, Chr(13), "m", "77", Chr(109) ' CR
    AddEntry 78, Chr(14), "n", "78", Chr(110) ' SO
    AddEntry 79, Chr(15), "o", "79", Chr(111) ' SI
    AddEntry 80, Chr(16), "p", "80", Chr(112) ' DLE
    AddEntry 81, Chr(17), "q", "81", Chr(113) ' DC1
    AddEntry 82, Chr(18), "r", "82", Chr(114) ' DC2
    AddEntry 83, Chr(19), "s", "83", Chr(115) ' DC3
    AddEntry 84, Chr(20), "t", "84", Chr(116) ' DC4
    AddEntry 85, Chr(21), "u", "85", Chr(117) ' NAK
    AddEntry 86, Chr(22), "v", "86", Chr(118) ' SYN
    AddEntry 87, Chr(23), "w", "87", Chr(119) ' ETB
    AddEntry 88, Chr(24), "x", "88", Chr(120) ' CAN
    AddEntry 89, Chr(25), "y", "89", Chr(121) ' EM
    AddEntry 90, Chr(26), "z", "90", Chr(122) ' SUB
    AddEntry 91, Chr(27), "{", "91", Chr(123) ' ESC
    AddEntry 92, Chr(28), "|", "92", Chr(124) ' FS
    AddEntry 93, Chr(29), "}", "93", Chr(125) ' GS
    AddEntry 94, Chr(30), "~", "94", Chr(126) ' RS
    AddEntry 95, Chr(31), Chr(127), "95", Chr(200) ' US, DEL
    AddEntry 96, "FNC 3", "FNC 3", "96", Chr(201)
    AddEntry 97, "FNC 2", "FNC 2", "97", Chr(202)
    AddEntry 98, "SHIFT", "SHIFT", "98", Chr(203)
    AddEntry 99, "CODE C", "CODE C", "99", Chr(204)
    AddEntry 100, "CODE B", "FNC 4", "CODE B", Chr(205)
    AddEntry 101, "FNC 4", "CODE A", "CODE A", Chr(206)
    AddEntry 102, "FNC 1", "FNC 1", "FNC 1", Chr(207)
    AddEntry 103, "Start A", "Start A", "Start A", Chr(208)
    AddEntry 104, "Start B", "Start B", "Start B", Chr(209)
    AddEntry 105, "Start C", "Start C", "Start C", Chr(210)
    AddEntry 106, "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", Chr(211)
End Sub

Private Sub AddEntry(ByVal Index As Integer, ASet As String, BSet As String, CSet As String, BarSpacePattern As String)
    With CodeArr(Index)
        .ASet = ASet
        .BSet = BSet
        .CSet = CSet
        .BarSpacePattern = Replace(BarSpacePattern, " ", "")
    End With
End Sub

Public Function Code128_Str(ByVal Str As String)
    Code128_Str = Replace(BuildStr(Str), " ", "")
End Function

Private Function BuildStr(ByVal Str As String) As String
    Dim SCode As eCode128Type, PrevSCode As eCode128Type
    Dim CurrChar As String, ArrIndex As Integer, CharIndex As Long
    Dim CheckDigit As Integer, CCodeIndex As Integer, TotalSum As Long

    SCode = eCode128_CodeSetB
    If Str Like "##*" Then SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC

    TotalSum = 0
    CharIndex = 1

    Select Case SCode
    Case eCode128_CodeSetA
        TotalSum = TotalSum + (103 * CharIndex)
        BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & Chr(208)
    Case eCode128_CodeSetB
        TotalSum = TotalSum + (104 * CharIndex)
        BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & Chr(209)
    Case eCode128_CodeSetC
        TotalSum = TotalSum + (105 * CharIndex)
        BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & Chr(210)
    End Select

    PrevSCode = SCode

    Do Until Len(Str) = 0
        If Str Like "####*" Then SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC

        If SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC And Mid(Str, 1, 2) Like "##" Then
            CurrChar = Mid(Str, 1, 2)
        Else
            CurrChar = Mid(Str, 1, 1)
        End If

        ArrIndex = GetCharIndex(CurrChar, SCode, True)

        If ArrIndex <> -1 Then
            If CodeArr(ArrIndex).BSet = CurrChar And ((SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC And CodeArr(ArrIndex).CSet <> CurrChar) Or (SCode = eCode128_CodeSetA And CodeArr(ArrIndex).ASet <> CurrChar)) Then
                SCode = eCode128_CodeSetB
            ElseIf CodeArr(ArrIndex).ASet = CurrChar And CodeArr(ArrIndex).BSet <> CurrChar Then
                SCode = eCode128_CodeSetA
            ElseIf CodeArr(ArrIndex).CSet = CurrChar Then
                SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC
            End If

            If PrevSCode <> SCode Then
                Select Case SCode
                Case eCode128_CodeSetA
                    CCodeIndex = GetCharIndex("CODE A", PrevSCode, False)
                Case eCode128_CodeSetB
                    CCodeIndex = GetCharIndex("CODE B", PrevSCode, False)
                Case eCode128_CodeSetC
                    CCodeIndex = GetCharIndex("CODE C", PrevSCode, False)
                End Select

                TotalSum = TotalSum + (CCodeIndex * CharIndex)
                BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & CodeArr(CCodeIndex).BarSpacePattern

                CharIndex = CharIndex + 1
                PrevSCode = SCode
            End If

            BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & CodeArr(ArrIndex).BarSpacePattern

            TotalSum = TotalSum + (ArrIndex * CharIndex)
            CharIndex = CharIndex + 1
        End If

        If SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC Then
            Str = Mid(Str, 3)
        Else
            Str = Mid(Str, 2)
        End If
    Loop

    CheckDigit = TotalSum Mod 103

    BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & CodeArr(CheckDigit).BarSpacePattern
    BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & Chr(211)
End Function

Private Function GetCharIndex(ByVal Char As String, ByVal CodeType As eCode128Type, ByVal Recurse As Boolean) As Integer
    Dim K As Long

    Select Case CodeType
    Case eCode128_CodeSetA
        For K = 0 To UBound(CodeArr)
            If Char = CodeArr(K).ASet Then Exit For
        Next K
    Case eCode128_CodeSetB
        For K = 0 To UBound(CodeArr)
            If Char = CodeArr(K).BSet Then Exit For
        Next K
    Case eCode128_CodeSetC
        For K = 0 To UBound(CodeArr)
            If Char = CodeArr(K).CSet Then Exit For
        Next K
    End Select

    If K = UBound(CodeArr) + 1 Then
        If Not Recurse Then
            GetCharIndex = -1
        Else
            Select Case CodeType
            Case eCode128_CodeSetA
                GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetC, False)
            Case eCode128_CodeSetB
                GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetA, False)
            Case eCode128_CodeSetC
                GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetB, False)
            End Select

            If GetCharIndex = -1 Then
                Select Case CodeType
                Case eCode128_CodeSetA
                    GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetB, False)
                Case eCode128_CodeSetB
                    GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetC, False)
                Case eCode128_CodeSetC
                    GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetA, False)
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    Else
        GetCharIndex = K
    End If
End Function

Public Function Code128_GetWidth(ByVal Str As String, Optional ByVal BarWidth As Integer = 1) As Long
    Dim K As Long, Width As Long

    Str = Replace(Code128_Str(Str), " ", "")
    Debug.Print Str
    For K = 1 To Len(Str)
        Width = Width + Val(Mid(Str, K, 1))
    Next K

    Code128_GetWidth = Width * BarWidth + (28 * BarWidth)
End Function



Private Sub Class_Terminate()

End Sub
```

Comment: `The usual reason for getting #Value with a UDF is that one of the input arguments cannot be converted to the correct type` according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170983/vba-udf-returning-value

Do you call the function in excel like `=Code128_str("TESTING")` ? With the Double quote

Comment: Thanks Larry! I was calling the function like `=Code128_Str(A1)` (where A1 is cell with the value to convert), but have also tried calling it like `=Code128_Str("TESTING")` and `=Code128_Str(1234)`. All of these return the same `#VALUE` error. Ideally, I need to figure out how to debug this code properly, because at the moment, there's no errors from the code itself, but somewhere along the line, something is causing issues.

Comment: Hi OP, my question now is you are calling the function from the excel spreadsheet or in VBA?

Comment: I'm calling the function from within the spreadsheet, within a cell.

Comment: Taking another look from your reference, you need to follow the instruction from the site `Did you instantiate the class? CodeArr isn't defined until the Class_Initialize() method is run. If you're using VBA, like me, add the .cls file as a class module then, in your form or report or whatever do something like:

Private Sub blNumber_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
Dim Str As String
Dim code As cls_Code128

Str = Me.blNumber.Value
Set code = New cls_Code128

Me.barcode.Value = code.Code128_Str(Str)
End Sub`


I am a bit busy right now, if you still fail to call it, I will come back later in an hour

Comment: Firstly, really appreciate the help, Larry. I've tried multiple different ways of calling the code. In terms of that last comment, I did add the cls file as a class module and then added a separate module, to instantiate the class (using the code the final poster added). That last bit of code, in the final post, doesn't make sense to me. I tried using that code, and then also tried editing it, in a way that makes more sense to me: 
`Public Function blNumber(Str As String)
    Dim code As cls_Code128
    Set code = New cls_Code128
    blNumber.Value = code.Code128_Str(Str)
End Function`

Comment: As the original link to the font download is defunct: it can be found eg [here](http://www.dafont.com/code-128.font).  Original font author's page in English [here](http://grandzebu.net/informatique/codbar-en/code128.htm)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's how to use it
You need to have

1. Module  (To store the UDF function which you can call from Excel
   spreadsheet)
2. Class Module (To store the class object)

**Module**
Where Class1 is the name of the Class Module

```
Public Function Code128_Str(ByVal Str As String) As String
Dim c As Class1
Set c = New Class1
Code128_Str = c.Code128_Str(Str)
End Function
```

**Class Module**

```
' ***    Made By Michael Ciurescu (CVMichael)   ***
'Modified by Paulo Cunha (pcunha) to work with char128.ttf on word or excel on 16/05/2011
'the font at in http://grandzebu.net/index.php?page=/informatique/codbar-en/code128.htm


' References:
' http://www.barcodeman.com/info/c128.php3

Private Enum eCode128Type
    eCode128_CodeSetA = 1
    eCode128_CodeSetB = 2
    eCode128_CodeSetC = 3
End Enum

Private Type tCode
    ASet As String
    BSet As String
    CSet As String
    BarSpacePattern As String
End Type

Private CodeArr() As tCode

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim CodeArr(106)

    AddEntry 0, " ", " ", "00", Chr(32)
    AddEntry 1, "!", "!", "01", Chr(33)
    AddEntry 2, """", """", "02", Chr(34)
    AddEntry 3, "#", "#", "03", Chr(35)
    AddEntry 4, "$", "$", "04", Chr(36)
    AddEntry 5, "%", "%", "05", Chr(37)
    AddEntry 6, "&", "&", "06", Chr(38)
    AddEntry 7, "'", "'", "07", Chr(39)
    AddEntry 8, "(", "(", "08", Chr(40)
    AddEntry 9, ")", ")", "09", Chr(41)
    AddEntry 10, "*", "*", "10", Chr(42)
    AddEntry 11, "+", "+", "11", Chr(43)
    AddEntry 12, ",", ",", "12", Chr(44)
    AddEntry 13, "-", "-", "13", Chr(45)
    AddEntry 14, ".", ".", "14", Chr(46)
    AddEntry 15, "/", "/", "15", Chr(47)
    AddEntry 16, "0", "0", "16", Chr(48)
    AddEntry 17, "1", "1", "17", Chr(49)
    AddEntry 18, "2", "2", "18", Chr(50)
    AddEntry 19, "3", "3", "19", Chr(51)
    AddEntry 20, "4", "4", "20", Chr(52)
    AddEntry 21, "5", "5", "21", Chr(53)
    AddEntry 22, "6", "6", "22", Chr(54)
    AddEntry 23, "7", "7", "23", Chr(55)
    AddEntry 24, "8", "8", "24", Chr(56)
    AddEntry 25, "9", "9", "25", Chr(57)
    AddEntry 26, ":", ":", "26", Chr(58)
    AddEntry 27, ";", ";", "27", Chr(59)
    AddEntry 28, "<", "<", "28", Chr(60)
    AddEntry 29, "=", "=", "29", Chr(61)
    AddEntry 30, ">", ">", "30", Chr(62)
    AddEntry 31, "?", "?", "31", Chr(63)
    AddEntry 32, "@", "@", "32", Chr(64)
    AddEntry 33, "A", "A", "33", Chr(65)
    AddEntry 34, "B", "B", "34", Chr(66)
    AddEntry 35, "C", "C", "35", Chr(67)
    AddEntry 36, "D", "D", "36", Chr(68)
    AddEntry 37, "E", "E", "37", Chr(69)
    AddEntry 38, "F", "F", "38", Chr(70)
    AddEntry 39, "G", "G", "39", Chr(71)
    AddEntry 40, "H", "H", "40", Chr(72)
    AddEntry 41, "I", "I", "41", Chr(73)
    AddEntry 42, "J", "J", "42", Chr(74)
    AddEntry 43, "K", "K", "43", Chr(75)
    AddEntry 44, "L", "L", "44", Chr(76)
    AddEntry 45, "M", "M", "45", Chr(77)
    AddEntry 46, "N", "N", "46", Chr(78)
    AddEntry 47, "O", "O", "47", Chr(79)
    AddEntry 48, "P", "P", "48", Chr(80)
    AddEntry 49, "Q", "Q", "49", Chr(81)
    AddEntry 50, "R", "R", "50", Chr(82)
    AddEntry 51, "S", "S", "51", Chr(83)
    AddEntry 52, "T", "T", "52", Chr(84)
    AddEntry 53, "U", "U", "53", Chr(85)
    AddEntry 54, "V", "V", "54", Chr(86)
    AddEntry 55, "W", "W", "55", Chr(87)
    AddEntry 56, "X", "X", "56", Chr(88)
    AddEntry 57, "Y", "Y", "57", Chr(89)
    AddEntry 58, "Z", "Z", "58", Chr(90)
    AddEntry 59, "[", "[", "59", Chr(91)
    AddEntry 60, "\", "\", "60", Chr(92)
    AddEntry 61, "]", "]", "61", Chr(93)
    AddEntry 62, "^", "^", "62", Chr(94)
    AddEntry 63, "_", "_", "63", Chr(95)
    AddEntry 64, Chr(0), "`", "64", Chr(96) ' Null
    AddEntry 65, Chr(1), "a", "65", Chr(97) ' SOH
    AddEntry 66, Chr(2), "b", "66", Chr(98) ' STX
    AddEntry 67, Chr(3), "c", "67", Chr(99) ' ETX
    AddEntry 68, Chr(4), "d", "68", Chr(100) ' EOT
    AddEntry 69, Chr(5), "e", "69", Chr(101) ' ENQ
    AddEntry 70, Chr(6), "f", "70", Chr(102) ' ACK
    AddEntry 71, Chr(7), "g", "71", Chr(103) ' BEL
    AddEntry 72, Chr(8), "h", "72", Chr(104) ' BS
    AddEntry 73, Chr(9), "i", "73", Chr(105) ' HT
    AddEntry 74, Chr(10), "j", "74", Chr(106) ' LF
    AddEntry 75, Chr(11), "k", "75", Chr(107) ' VT
    AddEntry 76, Chr(12), "l", "76", Chr(108) ' FF
    AddEntry 77, Chr(13), "m", "77", Chr(109) ' CR
    AddEntry 78, Chr(14), "n", "78", Chr(110) ' SO
    AddEntry 79, Chr(15), "o", "79", Chr(111) ' SI
    AddEntry 80, Chr(16), "p", "80", Chr(112) ' DLE
    AddEntry 81, Chr(17), "q", "81", Chr(113) ' DC1
    AddEntry 82, Chr(18), "r", "82", Chr(114) ' DC2
    AddEntry 83, Chr(19), "s", "83", Chr(115) ' DC3
    AddEntry 84, Chr(20), "t", "84", Chr(116) ' DC4
    AddEntry 85, Chr(21), "u", "85", Chr(117) ' NAK
    AddEntry 86, Chr(22), "v", "86", Chr(118) ' SYN
    AddEntry 87, Chr(23), "w", "87", Chr(119) ' ETB
    AddEntry 88, Chr(24), "x", "88", Chr(120) ' CAN
    AddEntry 89, Chr(25), "y", "89", Chr(121) ' EM
    AddEntry 90, Chr(26), "z", "90", Chr(122) ' SUB
    AddEntry 91, Chr(27), "{", "91", Chr(123) ' ESC
    AddEntry 92, Chr(28), "|", "92", Chr(124) ' FS
    AddEntry 93, Chr(29), "}", "93", Chr(125) ' GS
    AddEntry 94, Chr(30), "~", "94", Chr(126) ' RS
    AddEntry 95, Chr(31), Chr(127), "95", Chr(200) ' US, DEL
    AddEntry 96, "FNC 3", "FNC 3", "96", Chr(201)
    AddEntry 97, "FNC 2", "FNC 2", "97", Chr(202)
    AddEntry 98, "SHIFT", "SHIFT", "98", Chr(203)
    AddEntry 99, "CODE C", "CODE C", "99", Chr(204)
    AddEntry 100, "CODE B", "FNC 4", "CODE B", Chr(205)
    AddEntry 101, "FNC 4", "CODE A", "CODE A", Chr(206)
    AddEntry 102, "FNC 1", "FNC 1", "FNC 1", Chr(207)
    AddEntry 103, "Start A", "Start A", "Start A", Chr(208)
    AddEntry 104, "Start B", "Start B", "Start B", Chr(209)
    AddEntry 105, "Start C", "Start C", "Start C", Chr(210)
    AddEntry 106, "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", Chr(211)
End Sub

Private Sub AddEntry(ByVal Index As Integer, ASet As String, BSet As String, CSet As String, BarSpacePattern As String)
    With CodeArr(Index)
        .ASet = ASet
        .BSet = BSet
        .CSet = CSet
        .BarSpacePattern = Replace(BarSpacePattern, " ", "")
    End With
End Sub

Public Function Code128_Str(ByVal Str As String)
    Code128_Str = Replace(BuildStr(Str), " ", "")
End Function

Private Function BuildStr(ByVal Str As String) As String
    Dim SCode As eCode128Type, PrevSCode As eCode128Type
    Dim CurrChar As String, ArrIndex As Integer, CharIndex As Long
    Dim CheckDigit As Integer, CCodeIndex As Integer, TotalSum As Long

    SCode = eCode128_CodeSetB
    If Str Like "##*" Then SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC

    TotalSum = 0
    CharIndex = 1

    Select Case SCode
    Case eCode128_CodeSetA
        TotalSum = TotalSum + (103 * CharIndex)
        BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & Chr(208)
    Case eCode128_CodeSetB
        TotalSum = TotalSum + (104 * CharIndex)
        BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & Chr(209)
    Case eCode128_CodeSetC
        TotalSum = TotalSum + (105 * CharIndex)
        BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & Chr(210)
    End Select

    PrevSCode = SCode

    Do Until Len(Str) = 0
        If Str Like "####*" Then SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC

        If SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC And Mid(Str, 1, 2) Like "##" Then
            CurrChar = Mid(Str, 1, 2)
        Else
            CurrChar = Mid(Str, 1, 1)
        End If

        ArrIndex = GetCharIndex(CurrChar, SCode, True)

        If ArrIndex <> -1 Then
            If CodeArr(ArrIndex).BSet = CurrChar And ((SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC And CodeArr(ArrIndex).CSet <> CurrChar) Or (SCode = eCode128_CodeSetA And CodeArr(ArrIndex).ASet <> CurrChar)) Then
                SCode = eCode128_CodeSetB
            ElseIf CodeArr(ArrIndex).ASet = CurrChar And CodeArr(ArrIndex).BSet <> CurrChar Then
                SCode = eCode128_CodeSetA
            ElseIf CodeArr(ArrIndex).CSet = CurrChar Then
                SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC
            End If

            If PrevSCode <> SCode Then
                Select Case SCode
                Case eCode128_CodeSetA
                    CCodeIndex = GetCharIndex("CODE A", PrevSCode, False)
                Case eCode128_CodeSetB
                    CCodeIndex = GetCharIndex("CODE B", PrevSCode, False)
                Case eCode128_CodeSetC
                    CCodeIndex = GetCharIndex("CODE C", PrevSCode, False)
                End Select

                TotalSum = TotalSum + (CCodeIndex * CharIndex)
                BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & CodeArr(CCodeIndex).BarSpacePattern

                CharIndex = CharIndex + 1
                PrevSCode = SCode
            End If

            BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & CodeArr(ArrIndex).BarSpacePattern

            TotalSum = TotalSum + (ArrIndex * CharIndex)
            CharIndex = CharIndex + 1
        End If

        If SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC Then
            Str = Mid(Str, 3)
        Else
            Str = Mid(Str, 2)
        End If
    Loop

    CheckDigit = TotalSum Mod 103

    BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & CodeArr(CheckDigit).BarSpacePattern
    BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & Chr(211)
End Function

Private Function GetCharIndex(ByVal Char As String, ByVal CodeType As eCode128Type, ByVal Recurse As Boolean) As Integer
    Dim K As Long

    Select Case CodeType
    Case eCode128_CodeSetA
        For K = 0 To UBound(CodeArr)
            If Char = CodeArr(K).ASet Then Exit For
        Next K
    Case eCode128_CodeSetB
        For K = 0 To UBound(CodeArr)
            If Char = CodeArr(K).BSet Then Exit For
        Next K
    Case eCode128_CodeSetC
        For K = 0 To UBound(CodeArr)
            If Char = CodeArr(K).CSet Then Exit For
        Next K
    End Select

    If K = UBound(CodeArr) + 1 Then
        If Not Recurse Then
            GetCharIndex = -1
        Else
            Select Case CodeType
            Case eCode128_CodeSetA
                GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetC, False)
            Case eCode128_CodeSetB
                GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetA, False)
            Case eCode128_CodeSetC
                GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetB, False)
            End Select

            If GetCharIndex = -1 Then
                Select Case CodeType
                Case eCode128_CodeSetA
                    GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetB, False)
                Case eCode128_CodeSetB
                    GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetC, False)
                Case eCode128_CodeSetC
                    GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetA, False)
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    Else
        GetCharIndex = K
    End If
End Function

Public Function Code128_GetWidth(ByVal Str As String, Optional ByVal BarWidth As Integer = 1) As Long
    Dim K As Long, Width As Long

    Str = Replace(Code128_Str(Str), " ", "")
    Debug.Print Str
    For K = 1 To Len(Str)
        Width = Width + Val(Mid(Str, K, 1))
    Next K

    Code128_GetWidth = Width * BarWidth + (28 * BarWidth)
End Function



Private Sub Class_Terminate()

End Sub
```

Then in SpreadSheet, in any cell , you can call like
`=Code128_Str("TESTING")`
or
`=Code128_Str(A1)`

Comment: Perfect :) . Thanks a lot for your help, Larry. Will vote up this answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: no problem, I am learning VBA myself by the question you post.

Comment: The links to the font and code no longer work. Does anybody have another reference for the font?

Comment: perfect explanation and looks great, but I get in the result an "Ó" att he end of the text and a "Ò" at the beginning - is this how it should be?

Comment: it seems I'm doing something wrong; this is what I get: http://k18.imgup.net/ScreenShotb4d1.png

Answer (score 8):

Larry's code is brilliant, but I only found one small issue.  (I would've commented on his answer but I don't have enough reputation points).  I was having issues when I was encoding double zeros.  For example "1200".  "00" translates to a space.  There are numerous places in the code where it "trims" spaces or it "replaces" spaces.  When I would try to encode "1200" the resulting bar code would only be "12".  To fix this I removed the applicable "trims" and "replaces" as follows.  The code below is only the Class Module.  Please refer to Larry's post for the Module code.

**Class Module**

```
' ***    Made By Michael Ciurescu (CVMichael)   ***
'Modified by Paulo Cunha (pcunha) to work with char128.ttf on word or excel on 16/05/2011
'the font at in http://grandzebu.net/index.php?page=/informatique/codbar-en/code128.htm
' References:
' http://www.barcodeman.com/info/c128.php3

Private Enum eCode128Type
    eCode128_CodeSetA = 1
    eCode128_CodeSetB = 2
    eCode128_CodeSetC = 3
End Enum

Private Type tCode
    ASet As String
    BSet As String
    CSet As String
    BarSpacePattern As String
End Type

Private CodeArr() As tCode

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim CodeArr(106)

    AddEntry 0, " ", " ", "00", Chr(32)
    AddEntry 1, "!", "!", "01", Chr(33)
    AddEntry 2, """", """", "02", Chr(34)
    AddEntry 3, "#", "#", "03", Chr(35)
    AddEntry 4, "$", "$", "04", Chr(36)
    AddEntry 5, "%", "%", "05", Chr(37)
    AddEntry 6, "&", "&", "06", Chr(38)
    AddEntry 7, "'", "'", "07", Chr(39)
    AddEntry 8, "(", "(", "08", Chr(40)
    AddEntry 9, ")", ")", "09", Chr(41)
    AddEntry 10, "*", "*", "10", Chr(42)
    AddEntry 11, "+", "+", "11", Chr(43)
    AddEntry 12, ",", ",", "12", Chr(44)
    AddEntry 13, "-", "-", "13", Chr(45)
    AddEntry 14, ".", ".", "14", Chr(46)
    AddEntry 15, "/", "/", "15", Chr(47)
    AddEntry 16, "0", "0", "16", Chr(48)
    AddEntry 17, "1", "1", "17", Chr(49)
    AddEntry 18, "2", "2", "18", Chr(50)
    AddEntry 19, "3", "3", "19", Chr(51)
    AddEntry 20, "4", "4", "20", Chr(52)
    AddEntry 21, "5", "5", "21", Chr(53)
    AddEntry 22, "6", "6", "22", Chr(54)
    AddEntry 23, "7", "7", "23", Chr(55)
    AddEntry 24, "8", "8", "24", Chr(56)
    AddEntry 25, "9", "9", "25", Chr(57)
    AddEntry 26, ":", ":", "26", Chr(58)
    AddEntry 27, ";", ";", "27", Chr(59)
    AddEntry 28, "<", "<", "28", Chr(60)
    AddEntry 29, "=", "=", "29", Chr(61)
    AddEntry 30, ">", ">", "30", Chr(62)
    AddEntry 31, "?", "?", "31", Chr(63)
    AddEntry 32, "@", "@", "32", Chr(64)
    AddEntry 33, "A", "A", "33", Chr(65)
    AddEntry 34, "B", "B", "34", Chr(66)
    AddEntry 35, "C", "C", "35", Chr(67)
    AddEntry 36, "D", "D", "36", Chr(68)
    AddEntry 37, "E", "E", "37", Chr(69)
    AddEntry 38, "F", "F", "38", Chr(70)
    AddEntry 39, "G", "G", "39", Chr(71)
    AddEntry 40, "H", "H", "40", Chr(72)
    AddEntry 41, "I", "I", "41", Chr(73)
    AddEntry 42, "J", "J", "42", Chr(74)
    AddEntry 43, "K", "K", "43", Chr(75)
    AddEntry 44, "L", "L", "44", Chr(76)
    AddEntry 45, "M", "M", "45", Chr(77)
    AddEntry 46, "N", "N", "46", Chr(78)
    AddEntry 47, "O", "O", "47", Chr(79)
    AddEntry 48, "P", "P", "48", Chr(80)
    AddEntry 49, "Q", "Q", "49", Chr(81)
    AddEntry 50, "R", "R", "50", Chr(82)
    AddEntry 51, "S", "S", "51", Chr(83)
    AddEntry 52, "T", "T", "52", Chr(84)
    AddEntry 53, "U", "U", "53", Chr(85)
    AddEntry 54, "V", "V", "54", Chr(86)
    AddEntry 55, "W", "W", "55", Chr(87)
    AddEntry 56, "X", "X", "56", Chr(88)
    AddEntry 57, "Y", "Y", "57", Chr(89)
    AddEntry 58, "Z", "Z", "58", Chr(90)
    AddEntry 59, "[", "[", "59", Chr(91)
    AddEntry 60, "\", "\", "60", Chr(92)
    AddEntry 61, "]", "]", "61", Chr(93)
    AddEntry 62, "^", "^", "62", Chr(94)
    AddEntry 63, "_", "_", "63", Chr(95)
    AddEntry 64, Chr(0), "`", "64", Chr(96) ' Null
    AddEntry 65, Chr(1), "a", "65", Chr(97) ' SOH
    AddEntry 66, Chr(2), "b", "66", Chr(98) ' STX
    AddEntry 67, Chr(3), "c", "67", Chr(99) ' ETX
    AddEntry 68, Chr(4), "d", "68", Chr(100) ' EOT
    AddEntry 69, Chr(5), "e", "69", Chr(101) ' ENQ
    AddEntry 70, Chr(6), "f", "70", Chr(102) ' ACK
    AddEntry 71, Chr(7), "g", "71", Chr(103) ' BEL
    AddEntry 72, Chr(8), "h", "72", Chr(104) ' BS
    AddEntry 73, Chr(9), "i", "73", Chr(105) ' HT
    AddEntry 74, Chr(10), "j", "74", Chr(106) ' LF
    AddEntry 75, Chr(11), "k", "75", Chr(107) ' VT
    AddEntry 76, Chr(12), "l", "76", Chr(108) ' FF
    AddEntry 77, Chr(13), "m", "77", Chr(109) ' CR
    AddEntry 78, Chr(14), "n", "78", Chr(110) ' SO
    AddEntry 79, Chr(15), "o", "79", Chr(111) ' SI
    AddEntry 80, Chr(16), "p", "80", Chr(112) ' DLE
    AddEntry 81, Chr(17), "q", "81", Chr(113) ' DC1
    AddEntry 82, Chr(18), "r", "82", Chr(114) ' DC2
    AddEntry 83, Chr(19), "s", "83", Chr(115) ' DC3
    AddEntry 84, Chr(20), "t", "84", Chr(116) ' DC4
    AddEntry 85, Chr(21), "u", "85", Chr(117) ' NAK
    AddEntry 86, Chr(22), "v", "86", Chr(118) ' SYN
    AddEntry 87, Chr(23), "w", "87", Chr(119) ' ETB
    AddEntry 88, Chr(24), "x", "88", Chr(120) ' CAN
    AddEntry 89, Chr(25), "y", "89", Chr(121) ' EM
    AddEntry 90, Chr(26), "z", "90", Chr(122) ' SUB
    AddEntry 91, Chr(27), "{", "91", Chr(123) ' ESC
    AddEntry 92, Chr(28), "|", "92", Chr(124) ' FS
    AddEntry 93, Chr(29), "}", "93", Chr(125) ' GS
    AddEntry 94, Chr(30), "~", "94", Chr(126) ' RS
    AddEntry 95, Chr(31), Chr(127), "95", Chr(200) ' US, DEL
    AddEntry 96, "FNC 3", "FNC 3", "96", Chr(201)
    AddEntry 97, "FNC 2", "FNC 2", "97", Chr(202)
    AddEntry 98, "SHIFT", "SHIFT", "98", Chr(203)
    AddEntry 99, "CODE C", "CODE C", "99", Chr(204)
    AddEntry 100, "CODE B", "FNC 4", "CODE B", Chr(205)
    AddEntry 101, "FNC 4", "CODE A", "CODE A", Chr(206)
    AddEntry 102, "FNC 1", "FNC 1", "FNC 1", Chr(207)
    AddEntry 103, "Start A", "Start A", "Start A", Chr(208)
    AddEntry 104, "Start B", "Start B", "Start B", Chr(209)
    AddEntry 105, "Start C", "Start C", "Start C", Chr(210)
    AddEntry 106, "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", Chr(211)
End Sub

Private Sub AddEntry(ByVal Index As Integer, ASet As String, BSet As String, CSet As String, BarSpacePattern As String)
    With CodeArr(Index)
        .ASet = ASet
        .BSet = BSet
        .CSet = CSet
        '.BarSpacePattern = Replace(BarSpacePattern, " ", "")
        .BarSpacePattern = BarSpacePattern
    End With
End Sub

Public Function Code128_Str(ByVal Str As String)
    'Code128_Str = Replace(BuildStr(Str), " ", "")
    Code128_Str = BuildStr(Str)
End Function

Private Function BuildStr(ByVal Str As String) As String
    Dim SCode As eCode128Type, PrevSCode As eCode128Type
    Dim CurrChar As String, ArrIndex As Integer, CharIndex As Long
    Dim CheckDigit As Integer, CCodeIndex As Integer, TotalSum As Long

    SCode = eCode128_CodeSetB
    If Str Like "##*" Then SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC

    TotalSum = 0
    CharIndex = 1

    Select Case SCode
    Case eCode128_CodeSetA
        TotalSum = TotalSum + (103 * CharIndex)
        BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & Chr(208)
    Case eCode128_CodeSetB
        TotalSum = TotalSum + (104 * CharIndex)
        BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & Chr(209)
    Case eCode128_CodeSetC
        TotalSum = TotalSum + (105 * CharIndex)
        BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & Chr(210)
    End Select

    PrevSCode = SCode

    Do Until Len(Str) = 0
        If Str Like "####*" Then SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC

        If SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC And Mid(Str, 1, 2) Like "##" Then
            CurrChar = Mid(Str, 1, 2)
        Else
            CurrChar = Mid(Str, 1, 1)
        End If

        ArrIndex = GetCharIndex(CurrChar, SCode, True)

        If ArrIndex <> -1 Then
            If CodeArr(ArrIndex).BSet = CurrChar And ((SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC And CodeArr(ArrIndex).CSet <> CurrChar) Or (SCode = eCode128_CodeSetA And CodeArr(ArrIndex).ASet <> CurrChar)) Then
                SCode = eCode128_CodeSetB
            ElseIf CodeArr(ArrIndex).ASet = CurrChar And CodeArr(ArrIndex).BSet <> CurrChar Then
                SCode = eCode128_CodeSetA
            ElseIf CodeArr(ArrIndex).CSet = CurrChar Then
                SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC
            End If

            If PrevSCode <> SCode Then
                Select Case SCode
                Case eCode128_CodeSetA
                    CCodeIndex = GetCharIndex("CODE A", PrevSCode, False)
                Case eCode128_CodeSetB
                    CCodeIndex = GetCharIndex("CODE B", PrevSCode, False)
                Case eCode128_CodeSetC
                    CCodeIndex = GetCharIndex("CODE C", PrevSCode, False)
                End Select

                TotalSum = TotalSum + (CCodeIndex * CharIndex)
                'BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & CodeArr(CCodeIndex).BarSpacePattern
                BuildStr = BuildStr & CodeArr(CCodeIndex).BarSpacePattern

                CharIndex = CharIndex + 1
                PrevSCode = SCode
            End If

            'BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & CodeArr(ArrIndex).BarSpacePattern
            BuildStr = BuildStr & CodeArr(ArrIndex).BarSpacePattern

            TotalSum = TotalSum + (ArrIndex * CharIndex)
            CharIndex = CharIndex + 1
        End If

        If SCode = eCode128_CodeSetC Then
            Str = Mid(Str, 3)
        Else
            Str = Mid(Str, 2)
        End If
    Loop

    CheckDigit = TotalSum Mod 103

    'BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & CodeArr(CheckDigit).BarSpacePattern
    BuildStr = BuildStr & CodeArr(CheckDigit).BarSpacePattern
    'BuildStr = Trim(BuildStr) & Chr(211)
    BuildStr = BuildStr & Chr(211)
End Function

Private Function GetCharIndex(ByVal Char As String, ByVal CodeType As eCode128Type, ByVal Recurse As Boolean) As Integer
    Dim K As Long

    Select Case CodeType
    Case eCode128_CodeSetA
        For K = 0 To UBound(CodeArr)
            If Char = CodeArr(K).ASet Then Exit For
        Next K
    Case eCode128_CodeSetB
        For K = 0 To UBound(CodeArr)
            If Char = CodeArr(K).BSet Then Exit For
        Next K
    Case eCode128_CodeSetC
        For K = 0 To UBound(CodeArr)
            If Char = CodeArr(K).CSet Then Exit For
        Next K
    End Select

    If K = UBound(CodeArr) + 1 Then
        If Not Recurse Then
            GetCharIndex = -1
        Else
            Select Case CodeType
            Case eCode128_CodeSetA
                GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetC, False)
            Case eCode128_CodeSetB
                GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetA, False)
            Case eCode128_CodeSetC
                GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetB, False)
            End Select

            If GetCharIndex = -1 Then
                Select Case CodeType
                Case eCode128_CodeSetA
                    GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetB, False)
                Case eCode128_CodeSetB
                    GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetC, False)
                Case eCode128_CodeSetC
                    GetCharIndex = GetCharIndex(Char, eCode128_CodeSetA, False)
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    Else
        GetCharIndex = K
    End If
End Function

Public Function Code128_GetWidth(ByVal Str As String, Optional ByVal BarWidth As Integer = 1) As Long
    Dim K As Long, Width As Long

    Str = Replace(Code128_Str(Str), " ", "")
    Debug.Print Str
    For K = 1 To Len(Str)
        Width = Width + Val(Mid(Str, K, 1))
    Next K

    Code128_GetWidth = Width * BarWidth + (28 * BarWidth)
End Function



Private Sub Class_Terminate()

End Sub
```