# Get actual width of text in a particular font configuration?

Tags: vba, excel, barcode

I am printing barcodes and as part of the process I have a Chart object which has a textbox on it.

I render the barcode on it using the clsBarcode class I got from here
[Generating Code 128 Barcodes using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909248/generating-code-128-barcodes-using-excel-vba)

Now the issue I have is that I can't tell the width of the barcode.

I generate the barcode on that chart object and then .export the chart as a jpeg file.  I had been using a fixed size for the chart object but now I'm trying to print barcodes of different sizes and have to adjust the chart object to match the barcode size or else it gets clipped.

I found an strWidth function here
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=94339

Unfortunately it uses a lookup table for commonly available fonts. There is no entry in the table for code128.fft.

So I am kind of stuck here.  If I just resize my chart to be the long possible size of any barcode then I get a lot of wasted whitespace in my barcode image. And since I am printing these barcodes on 2"x4" stickers, you can guess space is at a premium.

I think the best course would be to populate the lookup table with values for code128 characters.  The barcode class indicates that chr 32 to 126 and 200 to 211 are in use.

How can I figure out the mafChrWid(i) values for these chars ?

thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this function you need to name a cell BARCODE and set it's font code128.fft.

```
Function getBarCodeWidth(strBarcode As String) As Double

    With Range("BARCODE")
        .Formula = "=Code128_Str(" & strBarcode & ")"
        .Worksheet.Columns(.Column).AutoFit
        getBarCodeWidth = .Width
    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember where I got the original code to determine font size. I modified it into an easy to use function that can be used to automatically resize a textbox to fit its contents. Drop the below code into its own module and you can then getLabelPixel(theControlYouWantToSizeToItsContents) as the textbox width.

```
Private Declare Function CreateDC Lib "gdi32.dll" Alias "CreateDCA" (ByVal lpDriverName As String, ByVal lpDeviceName As String, ByVal lpOutput As String, lpInitData As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateFontIndirect Lib "gdi32.dll" Alias "CreateFontIndirectA" (lpLogFont As LOGFONT) As Long
Private Declare Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteObject Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetTextExtentPoint32 Lib "gdi32.dll" Alias "GetTextExtentPoint32A" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal lpsz As String, ByVal cbString As Long, lpSize As SIZE) As Long
Private Declare Function MulDiv Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal nNumber As Long, ByVal nNumerator As Long, ByVal nDenominator As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Const LOGPIXELSY As Long = 90

Private Type LOGFONT
    lfHeight As Long
    lfWidth As Long
    lfEscapement As Long
    lfOrientation As Long
    lfWeight As Long
    lfItalic As Byte
    lfUnderline As Byte
    lfStrikeOut As Byte
    lfCharSet As Byte
    lfOutPrecision As Byte
    lfClipPrecision As Byte
    lfQuality As Byte
    lfPitchAndFamily As Byte
    lfFaceName As String * 32
End Type

Private Type SIZE
    cx As Long
    cy As Long
End Type

Public Function getLabelPixel(textBox As Control) As Integer
    Dim font As New StdFont
    Dim sz As SIZE
    font.Name = textBox.FontName
    font.SIZE = textBox.FontSize
    font.Weight = textBox.FontWeight

    sz = GetLabelSize(textBox.Value, font)
    getLabelPixel = sz.cx * 15 + 50   'Multiply this by 15 to get size in twips and +50 to account for padding for access form. .cx is width for font height us .cy
End Function

Private Function GetLabelSize(text As String, font As StdFont) As SIZE
    Dim tempDC As Long
    Dim tempBMP As Long
    Dim f As Long
    Dim lf As LOGFONT
    Dim textSize As SIZE

    ' Create a device context and a bitmap that can be used to store a
    ' temporary font object
    tempDC = CreateDC("DISPLAY", vbNullString, vbNullString, ByVal 0)
    tempBMP = CreateCompatibleBitmap(tempDC, 1, 1)

    ' Assign the bitmap to the device context
    DeleteObject SelectObject(tempDC, tempBMP)

    ' Set up the LOGFONT structure and create the font
    lf.lfFaceName = font.Name & Chr$(0)
    lf.lfHeight = -MulDiv(font.SIZE, GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(0), 90), 72) 
    'LOGPIXELSY
    lf.lfItalic = font.Italic
    lf.lfStrikeOut = font.Strikethrough
    lf.lfUnderline = font.Underline
    lf.lfWeight = font.Weight
    'If font.Bold Then lf.lfWeight = 800 Else lf.lfWeight = 400
    f = CreateFontIndirect(lf)

    ' Assign the font to the device context
    DeleteObject SelectObject(tempDC, f)

    ' Measure the text, and return it into the textSize SIZE structure
    GetTextExtentPoint32 tempDC, text, Len(text), textSize

    ' Clean up (very important to avoid memory leaks!)
    DeleteObject f
    DeleteObject tempBMP
    DeleteDC tempDC
    ' Return the measurements

    GetLabelSize = textSize
End Function
```