# Code 128 Barcode in VBA for Access not working properly

Tags: vba, code128

I copied the code from this thread into my access db: [Generating Code 128 Barcodes using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909248/generating-code-128-barcodes-using-excel-vba)

The function runs properly and returns a modified string (for the following, I will use the string "standard284762", my databases unique ID format as example).

I downloaded this font: https://dl.dafont.com/dl/?f=code_128

When I execute the function, it converts the string into this:

`ÑstandardÌ<O^ÈÓ`

[image: code]

And it shows up like this on the Report:

[image]

I am using the Office 365 Version of Access.
My module is named `Code128str` and my class module is named `Class1`

Any ideas what causes the weird output?
Could anyone confirm that the code works fine and the Problem is somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the font from this page:  http://grandzebu.net/informatique/codbar-en/code128.htm

The font has to "pair" with the code.

Font download: http://grandzebu.net/informatique/codbar/code128.ttf

I saw the same problem before I installed that version of the font.

Comment: How did they differ?

Comment: From the linked page: "Version 2.00 of the font : The code of characters 95 and following was modified compared to the version 1.00. The encoding function was modified consequently."