# VBA Code returns error only for a certain clock

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I am getting an error message only for a certain block of code. I have tried following the instructions given here:

[VBA UDF returning #VALUE!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170983/vba-udf-returning-value)

However, it works just fine for most of the conditions, except the ones which have cl1=0

```
 Function catgate(cl1, cl2)

pgp = cl2 / cl1 - 1

If cl2 - cl1 < 0 And cl1 = 0 Then
catgate = -1
End If

If cl2 - cl1 > 0 And cl1 = 0 Then
catgate = 1
End If

If cl2 - cl1 = 0 And cl1 = 0 Then
catgate = 0
End If

If cl2 - cl1 < 0 And cl1 < 0 Then
catgate = Abs(pgp) * -1
End If

If cl2 - cl1 < 0 And cl1 > 0 Then
catgate = Abs(pgp) * -1
End If

If cl2 - cl1 = 0 And cl1 > 0 Then
catgate = 0
End If

If cl2 - cl1 > 0 And cl1 < 0 Then
catgate = Abs(pgp)
End If

If cl2 - cl1 > 0 And cl1 = 0 Then
catgate = 1
End If

If cl2 - cl1 > 0 And cl1 > 0 Then
catgate = Abs(pgp)
End If


End Function
```

please help

Comment: That worked! Thanks a ton!! I have been sitting on it for hours now :)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the first line of your function will generate an error if cl1 is **0**:

[image]